# java.sql.SQLException: Error opening connection OS=Linux AARCH64

Tags: linux, sqlite, jdbc, database-connection, raspberry-pi4

- My application uses SQLite database.
- Database is being accessed from Java application.
- And the application is deployed on Raspberry Pi 4
- java version "1.8.0_381"
- sqlite: sqlite-jdbc-3.44.1.0

The SQLite JDBC contains library for aarch 64

[image]

However while opening connection, the error says library not found.
what could be the cause?

```
org.sqlite.NativeLibraryNotFoundException: 
No native library found for os.name=Linux, os.arch=aarch64, paths=[/org/sqlite/native/Linux/aarch64:
/usr/java/packages/lib/arm:/lib:/usr/lib]
```

Code is as below

```
Class.forName(DEF_JDBC_CLASS_NAME);
Connection objConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + sDataBasePath);
```

Additional information:

- The issue does not occur if hardware is Raspberry Pi 2 or 3.
- Architecture of Raspberry Pi 4 is aarch64.
- However, Raspberry Pi 2 and 3 use a different architecture (armhf)

Comment: Also, that driver uses a service provider architecture, so you don't need to do `Class.forName` but you *do* need to use `DriverManager.getConnection`

Comment: @g00se Could not understand question actually? it will be helpful if you could be specific?

Comment: Actually you can ignore that question (I checked it). I deleted the question

Comment: @g00se understood. And I checked by commenting out Class.forName. Result did not change.

Comment: How are you running your app - as a jar or from a directory?

Comment: @g00se This java application is running as a Service on RaspberryPi.

Comment: How is that service invoking `java`?